# table component dataSource with nested elements

Tags: antd

There are many nice examples of how to use the table component [here](https://ant.design/components/table/). But all the examples have a datasource with a simple json format. What if we have json datasource had a nested element like:

```
const dataSource = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 32,
    address: {
      street: '10 Downing Street',
      state: 'VA',
      zip: 23012
    }
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'John',
    age: 42,
    address: {
      street: '10 Upper Street',
      state: 'MD',
      zip: 23033,
    }
  },
];
```

Is there a way we could define a column based on the state address?

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    key: 'age',
  },
  {
    title: 'State',
    dataIndex: 'address.state',
    key: 'address.state',
  },
];
```

What is the right approach to handle such a data source?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what works:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    key: 'age',
  },
  {
    title: 'State',
    dataIndex: ['address','state'],
    key: ['address','state'],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

`dataIndex` need to be matched with key level 1 of each item, but you can render by your need:

```
// when you set dataIndex, you don't need key in columns anymore, but you should have key your data item
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name'
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age'
  },
  {
    title: 'State',
    dataIndex: 'address.state',
    render: (address) => <div>{address.state}</div>
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get object in one column like this render & you have to remove dataIndex for that as below.

```
const columns = [
    {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
    },
    {
        title: 'Age',
        dataIndex: 'age',
        key: 'age',
    },
    {
        title: 'State',
        key: 'address',
        render: object => { console.log(object) }
    },
];
```